# Value from for each loop doesn't get returned

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, vue.js

I have a conditional `for-loop` in my Vue component. I only want to loop through the trainstations that have for example 'New York' as destination, or 'New York' is on the route.

```
<tr v-for="departure in filterTrainStations" :key="departure.name">
            <td>{{ departure.product.categoryCode }}</td>
            <td>{{ departure.direction }}</td>
            <td>{{ getTimeFromDate(departure.actualDateTime) }}</td>
            <td>{{ departure.name }} </td>
        </tr>
```

This is my table with `for-loop`. And it currently shows me all the trains with 'New York' as direction. But there are also trains with another direction but with 'New York' on their route. So I also want to check for those. This is my computed `filerTrainStations` function:

```
filterTrainStations: function() {

    // Direction where the train has to go to.
    const city = this.city.mediumName; // New York

    return this.response.payload.departures.filter(function(u) {
        // Only return the trains which go to the right direction. 
        if(u.direction === city) {
            return u;
        }   

        // Check if there are any trains with the desired city on their route.
        u.routeStations.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
            if(arrayItem.mediumName === city) {
                console.log(u);
                return u;
            }                    
        })
    }
)},
```

The value which should return from the `forEach` function doesn't return anything but when i `console.log` it it shows me the right information.

My question is:

> Why does the value the value `u` doesn't get returned?

My response from the API where I am retrieving the departure information from looks like this:

```
response: {
          "links": {},
            "payload": {
                "source": "PPV",
                "departures": [
                    {
                        "direction": "Weert",
                        "name": "NS  5249",
                        "plannedDateTime": "2019-10-10T15:08:00+0200",
                        "plannedTimeZoneOffset": 120,
                        "actualDateTime": "2019-10-10T15:08:00+0200",
                        "actualTimeZoneOffset": 120,
                        "plannedTrack": "1",
                        "product": {
                            "number": "5249",
                            "categoryCode": "SPR",
                            "shortCategoryName": "NS Sprinter",
                            "longCategoryName": "Sprinter",
                            "operatorCode": "NS",
                            "operatorName": "NS",
                            "type": "TRAIN"
                        },
                        "trainCategory": "SPR",
                        "cancelled": false,
                        "routeStations": [
                            {
                                "uicCode": "8400129",
                                "mediumName": "Boxtel"
                            },
                            {
                                "uicCode": "8400206",
                                "mediumName": "Eindhoven"
                            },
                            {
                                "uicCode": "8400245",
                                "mediumName": "Geldrop"
                            }
                        ],
                        "departureStatus": "INCOMING"
                    },
                ]
            },
            "meta": {}
          }
```

Comment: It's because it will be returning in the inner closure (the forEach) and not the outer one (the filter). It looks like using [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would be a better option.

Comment: It's not clear what that `forEach` is meant to be doing. It's inside a `filter` which is a strange place to have it. Is the `filter` meant to be checking two conditions and then returning `u`? [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) might be more appropriate in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your filter callback is not proper for what you want to achieve.
Try this one below :

```
filterTrainStations: function() {

    // Direction where the train has to go to.
    const city = this.city.mediumName; // New York

    return this.response.payload.departures.filter(function(u) {
        return u.direction == city || u.routeStations.some(function(rs){ rs.mediumName == city});
    });
)}
```

Let me know if this helps

EDIT: Made an edit to include your code as well, so that you can easier see how to use it!

Comment: You're probably right, but by returning anything truthy the filter will work, and so long as a `some` returns true (in your case) or the `find` returns non-null (in mine) the filter works probably how they expect.

Comment: Yup, your's is a solid answer aswell, the only thing i would change is the format, so that you end up with just a single return, instead of OPs original code format

Comment: Thanks, I kept the code close to the OP by design, but wouldnt do it that way myself. I've pointed them to your answer which IMO Is the right answer.

Comment: The function now only returns `true` or `false`, but no data. I believe your answer is right as it is much more clear than my selfmade `function` but how do I return the data instead of just `true` or `false`? Or do I have to modify my `v-for` in the `table`? @MKougiouris

Comment: I made an edit to better understand the placement of the statement, if you take it as it is it should work!

Answer (score 4):

> Why does the value the value u doesn't get returned?

Because the `return` statement just returns out of the function passed to `forEach` it does not return from the outer `filter` method. You should instead use `find` and return the result:

```
filterTrainStations: function() {

    // Direction where the train has to go to.
    const city = this.city.mediumName; // New York

    return this.response.payload.departures.filter(function(u) {
        // Only return the trains which go to the right direction. 
        if(u.direction === city) {
            return u;
        }   

        // Check if there are any trains with the desired city on their route.
        return u.routeStations.find(arrayItem => arrayItem.mediumName === city);
    }
)},
```

But this raises another issue - the lines of code are themselves inside a `filter` where you should be returning `true` or `false` depending on if you want that item included or not in the result. Without more info it is hard to reconcile the actual problem you're having. However, returning *anything* truthy will result in that `departures` item being included in the result.

Personally, I would do it as [MKougiouris answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58341547/219661) suggests, as it is much clearer.

Comment: It indeed doesn't feel right to return the values from inside a `filter`. I just want to return everything when the direction matches the city or the city is inside the routeStations array.

Comment: @Baspa see the other answer. It is far better way to achieve your goal.